# Attempting to filter large amounts of data and delete rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large table of info in excel.  What I am trying to do is filter it and delete certain rows (where total is blank in a column).

The code works it just takes forever.  There are over 30k rows in the table.

The total is a figure generated by VBA and not a formula so that isn't slowing it down.  I have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` when I run it so that should help.

I am not sure how to make it run faster.  I would have thought a loop may be even slower but happy to try some different methods.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lngLastRow = Worksheets("report").Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngFilter = Worksheets("report").Range("B7:n" & lngLastRow)
rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="0.00"

With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng2 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: The slowest operation in your code is _deleting row_. Actually deleting _non_ contiguous rows is slow, but deleting contiguous rows very fast. Try to sort your range on column with your criteria and then apply filter/delete rows.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense and will hopefully work.  It does when I do it in excel trying to record the code.

Comment: Might be faster to collect a list of the row numbers that need deletion, throw the range into an array, delete the rows there, redim and put the array back into the range. Working with arrays is always much faster.

Comment: I have learnt about arrays a while back but not used them since. I think I need to see if I can find my notes.

Answer (score 1):

You could speed up it a bit if it contains lots of calculted cells by turning the formula calculation off for the time the code is excecuted

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.EnableCalculation = False
Next
```

And of course turn it back on after the code is excecuted

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.EnableCalculation = True
Next
```